# Bounding the $\ell^{1}$ norm given the $\ell^{2}$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $x = (x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots) \in \ell^{2}$. If $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}n|x_{n}|^{2} \leq 1$, is it possible to bound $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}|x_{n}|$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it may even be possible that $\sum_n n|x_n|^2$ is finite but $\sum_n|x_n|$ diverges. For example, take $$x_n:=\frac 1{n\log n}.$$